Is it possible to show current long (truncated) line as overlay or similar?
Sometimes I edit stuff with long lines, e.g. org tables to be exported, and I'd like to see the whole line without truncation, but I don't want to untruncate all lines (in a table, that makes it hard to read).
I know one can do (setq-local auto-hscroll-mode 'current-line) (c.f. Scroll only current line when truncating lines ) but is there any function/package/snippet to just make an overlay or pos-tip or something that shows the whole line (as if only that line were wrapped)?
